# Сделать выборку из sql таблицы

Tags: sql

В sql таблице есть три поля: id, name, status
Данные этих полей могут повторяться, status от 1 до 5 и тоже может повторятся.
Как сделать выборку только тех данных, где status != 5 и если status = 5 другие данные такого же id не выводить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableName A
WHERE A.status != 5 -- Статус не 5
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableName B WHERE B.id=A.id AND B.status=5) -- Нет записи с тем же ID и статусом 5
```